# Is there a correlation between CentOS and RHEL versions?

Tags: centos, rhel

I am trying to install an HP NC364T (4 port ethernet adapter) onto a machine running CentOS 7, however HP only supplies drivers built for RedHat, SCO, SUSE, Sun and Solaris. I know CentOS is intended to be binary compatible with RedHat but installing any of their driver versions leads to dependency problems and a failure to install.

Of the RedHat offerings they are supplying drivers compatible with RHEL 6 Server, RHEL 5 Server, RHEL 4 and RHEL 3.

Many drivers fail as they claim to be incompatible, but the 5 and 6 drivers at least attempt to install, but fail on dependencies.

This might end up being a question of how to resolve dependencies, but I at least want to know which version of RedHat that CentOS 7 is meant to be akin to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS is based on RHEL directly. CentOS 7 is based on RHEL7 and so that's the version of RHEL most compatible. Since about CentOS 5 (I think) they've tried to match the CentOS version numbers with the RHEL version numbers. So CentOS 6 was RHEL 6 and CentOS 8 will be RHEL 8.

You may have to either do without the drivers or downgrade to Cent OS 6. If it's on Cent OS 7 already, that can't be an old install anyways.

Comment: Hmm so if I'm running 7 and they only have drivers to 6, that's pretty much me dead in the water? Are there other options, like getting legacy dependencies that will run on 7 to satisfy the dependencies? Perhaps I need to get the source code and recompile for 7? That would be fun...

Comment: The drivers may be written for a specific kernel version. I would recommend reinstalling with CentOS 6 and just installing the RHEL 6 drivers or putting the project on hold until the vendor writes RHEL 7 drivers. RHEL7 is still pretty new so they may just not have done it yet.

Comment: Obviously you can compile if you want, but it's probably going to be more work than doing one of the two above.

Comment: // , Where can we find out about plans or current tests for CEntOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

There are drivers for RHEL 7 for that network card available from HP. However they are not listed in the card's download web page at HP website. They are included with the "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Supplement for HP Service Pack for ProLiant 2014.06.0" (filename supspp-1.00.rhel7.en.tar.gz) available at HP website. Just decompress it and you'll find the RPM kmod-hp-e1000e-3.0.4.1-10.rhel7u0.x86_64.rpm which is the e1000e driver for RedHar 7. It should work with Centos 7. According to the relase notes, that is "HP Intel e1000e Drivers for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 x86_64" version 3.0.4.1-10 for the HP NC364T PCI Express Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter.

The links are: [Release notes](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/doc/p928103531/v100305/RHEL7.0Supplement-SPP2014.06.0ReleaseNotes.pdf) and [Download page](http://www.hp.com/swpublishing/MTX-2c77611793f54d5fb08ec6b150)

As an alternative, have you tried to use the e1000e drivers included with CentOS?

Comment: That's great to hear though I'm baffled to why they wouldn't be available on their own site. Right now I am using the e1000e drivers and after a lot of head scratching on the teaming that seems  to be working just as well.